# How to use the Desktop App converter (Desktop Bridge)

Tags: desktop-bridge

Just started on the process of converting my app to the windows store.

Having some hard time trying to figure out how to use the desktop app converter when the program comes in a zip package with additional files that needs to be included (Not just the EXE)

What i mean is typically speaking the users would download the zip file from the website and then extract it and run the EXE file. However in that zip file there's  things like Drivers and Languages, I suppose i can make an MSI but i wanted to see if this was possible.

Anyone knows a way to just convert the ZIP file using the desktop app converter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Desktop App Converter has an option to create a Windows App Package (.appx) from a regular folder. So you just need to unzip your ZIP file and point the DAC at the folder, specifying what EXE should be the entry point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter#no-installer-conversion  - note however, that you can't deploy drivers with a Windows App Package (.appx).